# how to solve an error on addEventListener in typescript notation

Tags: typescript, events, parameters

```
class ScriptLoader {

    private loadedScripts : Array<string> = new Array<string>();

    constructor(private head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0], ) {
        if (typeof(head) == "undefined")
            alert("A página não contém o elemento head.");
    }

    load(scripts: Array<string>) {
        scripts.forEach(element => {
            let node = document.createElement('script') as HTMLScriptElement;
            node.type = 'text/javascript';
            node.charset = 'utf-8';
            node.async = true;

            node.addEventListener('load', (el: HTMLScriptElement, ev: Event) => this.onLoad(el, ev), false);

            node.src = element;

            this.head.appendChild(node);
        });
    }

    onLoad(el: HTMLScriptElement, ev: Event) : any {
        this.loadedScripts.push(el.src)
    }  
}
```

error message:

No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "load", listener: (this: HTMLScriptElement, ev: Event) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(el: HTMLScriptElement, ev: Event) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: HTMLScriptElement, ev: Event) => any'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(el: HTMLScriptElement, ev: Event) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
      Type '(el: HTMLScriptElement, ev: Event) => any' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class ScriptLoader {

        private loadedScripts : Array<string> = new Array<string>();

        constructor(private head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0], ) {
            if (typeof(head) == "undefined")
                alert("A página não contém o elemento head.");
        }

        load(scripts: Array<string>) {
            scripts.forEach(element => {
                let node = document.createElement('script') as HTMLScriptElement;
                node.type = 'text/javascript';
                node.charset = 'utf-8';
                node.async = true;

                // fix
                node.addEventListener('load', () => this.onLoad(node), false);

                node.src = element;

                this.head.appendChild(node);
            });
        }

        onLoad(el: HTMLScriptElement/*, ev: Event*/) : any {
            this.loadedScripts.push(el.src)
        }  
    }
```